# How Do I Find the newest Date in an Array of Hashes and Return the Name Key/Value that Corresponds

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, hash, max

I have an array of hashes like this:

```
[
 {
  "Address": 25,
  "AlertType": 1,
  "Area": "North",
  "MeasureDate": "2019-02-01T00:01:01.001Z",
  "MeasureValue": -1
 },
{
  "Address": 26,
  "AlertType": 1,
  "Area": "West",
  "MeasureDate": "2016-04-12T15:13:11.733Z",
  "MeasureValue": -1
},
{
  "Address": 25,
  "AlertType": 1,
  "Area": "North",
  "MeasureDate": "2017-02-01T00:01:01.001Z",
  "MeasureValue": -1
}
      .
      .
      .
]
```

And I need to find the most recent date but return the Address from the corresponding hash. I've got the code that finds the newest date:

```
let newest = new Date(Math.min.apply(null, data.map(function(e) {
  return new Date(e.created_at);
})));
most_recent = newest;
```

But I can't seem to get the address to return. The code I've written just returns the date or address from the

```
let findEarliest = (name) => {
  let nameIndex = 0;
  data.forEach((date) => {
    if(date.created_at.includes(most_recent));
      nameIndex = data.indexOf(date);
  });
  return data[nameIndex].name;
};
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out. Sorts the <strike>hash</strike> array by `MeasureDate` and then returns the first element's `Address`.

```js
const hash = [
   {
  "Address": 1,
  "AlertType": 1,
  "Area": "North",
  "MeasureDate": "2010-02-01T00:01:01.001Z",
  "MeasureValue": -1
 },
 {
  "Address": 25,
  "AlertType": 1,
  "Area": "North",
  "MeasureDate": "2019-02-01T00:01:01.001Z",
  "MeasureValue": -1
 },
{
  "Address": 26,
  "AlertType": 1,
  "Area": "West",
  "MeasureDate": "2016-04-12T15:13:11.733Z",
  "MeasureValue": -1
},
{
  "Address": 20,
  "AlertType": 1,
  "Area": "North",
  "MeasureDate": "2017-02-01T00:01:01.001Z",
  "MeasureValue": -1
}
]

const latestAddress = hash.sort((a, b) => b.MeasureDate > a.MeasureDate)[0].Address

console.log(latestAddress)
```

Comment: Getting undefined with that.

Comment: If you run the code snippet in SO - it works for me. Are you running the code snippet in SO or trying it elsewhere? Are there any differences between the two?

Comment: I was trying it in my interpreter. The data is slightly different but I updated your code accordingly. The array is called data and the dates are called created_at. I actually found the data that I posted above here on Stack and used it because the date format matched. The only other thing I can think of is that the keys aren't strings. They're in this format... address: .. could that be it?

Comment: The keys in the objects must be strings, unless they're a [*keyed collection*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-keyed-collection) like *Map* or *Set*, etc.

Comment: This sort function should be `a.MeasureDate.localCompare(b.MeasureDate)`. As it is, the function will only return true or false, which coerce to 1 or 0 respectively. There is no -1 so `a == b` and `a > b` are sorted as equivalent.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the assist!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

**Updated 17/08/2017:**

[RobG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/257182/robg) warned me. This code is the best way right now

**Best way:**

```js
const lastAddresDetails = addressList.sort((a, b) => b.MeasureDate.localeCompare(a.MeasureDate))[0];

console.log(lastAddresDetails.Address)
```

**Other ways**

```js
const lastAddresDetails = addressList.sort((a, b) => b.MeasureDate > a.MeasureDate)[0];

console.log(lastAddresDetails.Address)
```

or

```js
var lastAdressDetails = addressList.sort(function (a, b) {
            return b.MeasureDate > a.MeasureDate;
        })[0];

console.log(lastAdressDetails.Address);
```

Comment: This treats `a == b` and `a > b` as equal in the sort, so will not reliably return the smallest value. You should use [*localeCompare*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-properties-of-the-string-prototype-object) which is specifically designed for ordering strings. See [*Sort array of objects by string property value in JavaScript*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value-in-javascript).